# C - fprintf isn't writing to file

Tags: c, unix, clang, freebsd

C - fprintf isn't writing to file, any idea why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    FILE* pfile=fopen("/home/user-vlad/Programming/C-other/meme.txt","r");
    if(pfile==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Stream is equal to NULL\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(pfile,"Hello");
    fclose(pfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler: clang, OS: FreeBSD

Comment: You've only opened the file for reading. Read the [manual page for `fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) and what the second argument means. The `"r"` means you only want to read. There are options for writing, appending, etc.

Comment: when a fopen error occurs (pfile is NULL) then use 'perror()' <read the man page for perror()> because then the system message for the error will be appended to the text that you placed in double quotes between the parens.  I.E. perror( "fopen fo meme.txt failed");

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file opens can be because you called `fopen()` with the argument `"r"`, that means read.

To write you can use the argument `"w"`

```
fopen("/home/user-vlad/Programming/C-other/meme.txt","w");
```

Or if the file already exists `"r+"`

```
fopen("/home/user-vlad/Programming/C-other/meme.txt","r+");
```

Or if the file already exists and you want to append you can use `"a"`

```
fopen("/home/user-vlad/Programming/C-other/meme.txt","a");
```

You can learn more on `fopen()` [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm).

Comment: no, the file exists already. I just want fprintf to write to an already existing file.

Comment: @CIAAbigguy Then you can use `"r+"`

Comment: Though writing a new file and printing to it does work

Comment: That does work but I want to add on to the file, not override it, in this case I have text in it and I want to write to a file that has "hello" in it then place the word, "world" into it

Comment: @CIAAbigguy please read the manual page for `fopen`. All the options are described there.

Comment: @CIAAbigguy you want to append, the option for that is `"a"` or `"a+"`

Comment: do not use 'r+' as that means want to read and write to new file.   use 'a' to append to an existing file